# Must strange site visitor user agent be avoided? If yes how?

Tags: performance, .htaccess, security, cpanel, user-agent

I am using shared hosting.
My site was showing "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
So i went to see visitors to my (SSL) site.
I found that instead of regular names in the "User Agent" list,
cpanel visitors list is showing

> user agent Expanse indexes the network perimeters of our customers. If you have any questions or concerns, please reach out to: scaninfo@example.com"

I want to know whether this is harmful and if yes,
How to avoid such unknown user agents?
Is there something i should do with ".htaccess" file?
Once again, i am using shared hosting (so, i have limited accessibility).

Comment: Expanse Inc looks to be a legitimate company that was acquired by Palo Alto Networks (Dec 2020). Have you tried reaching out to the e-mail address in the message to ask why they are scanning your site?https://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2020-12-15/palo-alto-networks-completes-acquisition-of-expanse

Comment: Even if it looks to be a legitimate company, why are they using such strange name rather than using standard "user agent" naming format?

Comment: I don't know, but the point here is that they look completely legitimate, and have been bought by one of the market leading Firewall companies. What I am trying to say here is why are you against e-mailing them directly and asking, given they have provided all the information you need to contact them?

Comment: @JamesWilson, because no one has time for that. Nor do we care who bought them, as if that's any kind of test in legitimacy?

Comment: Same this is happening to me, any news?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 0):

The `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` you saw when accessing your website had nothing to do with the visitor you saw in cpanel. You might have had a different issue with your server configuration/shared hosting provider.

That "visitor" was an internet crawler, most likely from Palo Alto Networks, who owns Expanse. Long story short, it shouldn't cause any harm. [They say](https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/t5/general-topics/spurious-hits-from-the-expanse-webcrawler/td-p/447239) that their crawlers are used to index/categorize URLs around the internet and/or [to spot malicious content](https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/t5/general-topics/incoming-traffic-from-palo-alto-ip-address/m-p/196156#M58472).

I advise you to ignore it, since there's not much you can do - I assume they have some ranges of IPs for their crawlers so you wouldn't be able to blacklist all of them anyway.