# Running a flask application with heroku I suddenly get "Expanse indexes the network perimeters of our customers". What does this mean?

Tags: python, http, flask, heroku

The application was running and working successfully but now - without having changed anything - I get this message and Im confused. The Application does some webscraping using selenium with chrome browser, some calculations and then returns some json data. Heroku logs say nothing but status=200, correctly showing the connection but with the above message. Nothing gets calculated or returned anymore

What does or could this mean?

Edit:

The message appears in the terminal when I look at the logs with

```
heroku logs -n 1500
```

Then I get

```
2021-03-26T07:59:16.... app[web.1]: 10.11.248.147 - - [26/march/2021:7:59:16 + 000] "GET /HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Expanse indexes the network perimeters of our customers."
2021-03-26T07:59:16.... heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=xxx.herokuapp.com request_id=16f2c074 fwd="34.77.162.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=172 protocol=https
```

I get those two lines for every request that I do eventhough at the beginning it worked and I didnt change anything in the code

I wrote the flask application by myself and it seems to work fine when I test locally so Im not sure where to start since I dont have any error messages, only the message above..

Comment: When you say you "get this message", what exactly does that mean? Is that something that shows up in your browser when you go to the web site? Is it an error message that appears in the terminal? Something else? Is this an application that you wrote? If so, where is the code? If not, then you are in the wrong place; Stack Overflow is not for tech support.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel

Hey, you are right I should have provided more information. I edited the question. However since I dont get any error messages and the (selfwritten) code seems to work fine when I test locally, im not sure what kind of code snippet to provide

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337677/must-strange-site-visitor-user-agent-be-avoided-if-yes-how help? I found it by copying and pasting the weird message (including quotation marks) into a search engine.

Comment: I also came across that question and will write a message to the mail adress provided
Hopefully it will help. Thanks!